# Messaging between page and content script in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension which injects codes below to opened page:

```
s = document.createElement "script"
s.src = "//example.com/my.js"
(document.head or document.documentElement).appendChild s
```

So it can load my javascript and run it in the page. But after my.js finishes its job, how can I send a message to my extension?

Thanks!

Comment: `postMessage` or `document.createEvent` + `event.initEvent` + `document.dispatchEvent`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I found the answer:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication